# how to make an asynchronous javascript function synchronous

Tags: javascript

Given a button and it's click action set to be (in `alpinejs`)

```
<button x-on:click.prevent|debounce.3s="response = run();" type="button">Run</button>
```

when the `run()` function is defined like this:

```
function run() {
  // captcha();
  let data = input();
  data = confirm(data);
...
  data = request(url, data);
  return data;
}
```

It is a synchronous function and it works nicely.

The recaptcha documentation (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) states that if the button click is to be protected with recaptcha, it has to look like:

```
async function captcha() {
  let resp;
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'run'}).then(function(token) {
        console.log(token);
        resp = run();
    });
  });
  return resp;
}
```

If the click action is set to be:

```
<button x-on:click.prevent|debounce.3s="response = await captcha();" type="button">Run</button>
```

It results to this error:

[image]

Can you please advise what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: added the return statement in the `captcha` function

Comment: The function `captcha` doesn't contain a return statement and implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: @jabaa thanks. added the return statement, the error message remains the same though, any idea?

Comment: The function `captcha` still doesn't have a return statement. The anonymous function inside the anonymous function inside `captcha` has a return statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: (I am processing the async/await approach)

Comment: You're returning `resp` before it's set. That implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: @jabaa can you advise a bit more, see new "edit" based on async/await syntax, I am doing sth wrong since I am getting the same error

Comment: @jabaa how to wait till `resp` is set?

Comment: In JavaScript you don't wait. You return a promise. You could promisify `grecaptcha.ready` applying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises. Then, you could await `grecaptcha.ready` and `grecaptcha.execute` using `await`/`async`.

Comment: @jabaa would you be so kind to post an answer? the syntax is overwhelming being honest on this one.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. No need for another duplicate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for others that will be in the same situation as I am, here is the solution.

first step, I made the `captcha` function to return a promise

```
function captcha() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'run'}).then(function(token) {
          resolve(token);
        });
      });
    });
}
```

second step,  async/await for the variable to become available

```
async function run() {
  let g_recaptcha_response = await captcha();
  document.forms['params'].elements['g_recaptcha_response'].value = g_recaptcha_response;
  let data = input();
  data = confirm(data);
  if (data['error'] === true) {
    return data;
  }
  let url = `${origin}/app/json`;
  data = request(url, data);
  // note: preparing for input / next request.
  document.forms['params'].elements['token_id'].value = data['token_id'];
  return data;
}
```

third step, create an IIFE at the top-level

```
(async function(){ let response = await run(); })();
```

Comment: Looks right to me. You could just do `run()`  though

Comment: Yes, initially it was like that. grecaptcha though added the above requirement.

Comment: It didn't though. You only need async if you call await inside the fn. In other words, `run()` is fine.